# Transactions and sqlalchemy

Tags: python, insert, transactions, sqlalchemy

I am trying to figure out how to insert many (in the order of 100k) records into a database using SQLAlchemy in Python 3. Everything points to using transactions. However, I am slightly confused as to how that is done.

Some pages state that you get a transaction from `connection.begin()`, others places say it is `session.begin()` and this page [here](http://www.rmunn.com/sqlalchemy-tutorial/tutorial.html) says it is `session.create_transaction()` which doesn't exist.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
def addToTable(listOfRows):
    engine = create_engine('postgresql+pypostgresql:///%s' % db,echo = False)
    Session = sessionmaker(bind = engine)
    session = Session()
    table = myTable(engine,session)

    for row in listOfRows:
       table.add(row)
    table.flush() ### ideally there would be a counter and you flush after a couple of thousand records


class myTable:

    def __init__(self,engine,session):
       self.engine  = engine
       self.session = session
       self.transaction =createTransaction()# Create transaction code here

   def add(self,row):
       newRow = tableRow(row) ## This just creates a representation of a row in the DB
       self.transaction.add(newRow)
       self.transaction.flush()

   def flush(self):
       self.transaction.commit()
```

Comment: That's weird. Why do you have the myTable class, and where are your models?

Comment: Sorry it's been stripped back as I didn't want to clutter it with more code, as my main problem is the transaction. The myTable class is just a representation of the table in the database and it calls the class tableRow which extends sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base. What do you mean by models?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I highly suggest that you do both tutorials before continuing on your trip with SQLAlchemy. They are really helpful and explain many concepts. Afterwards, I suggest you read [Using the Session](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html) as this then goes on to explain how the session fits into all of this.

To your problem, there are two solutions: One using the ORM and the other using the Core. The former is easier, the latter is faster. Let's take the easy road first. A transaction is only used to wrap all your statements into a single operation. That is, if something fails, you can abort all of it and are not left with something somewhere in between. So you most likely want a transaction, but it would work without one. Here is the quickest way:

```
with session.begin():
    session.add_all([tableRow(row) for row in listOfRows])
```

Depending on your data SQLAlchemy might even be able to optimize your `INSERT` statement in such a way that it executes multiple at a time. Here is what's going on:

- A transaction is started using `session.begin`
- The data is added (using `add_all`, but a loop with multiple `add` would also be fine)
- The session is committed. If something goes wrong here, the transaction will be aborted and you can fix the error.

So this is clearly a good way, but it is not the fastest way, because SQLAlchemy has to go through all the ORM algorithms which can produce somewhat of an overhead. If this is a one-time database initialization, you can avoid the ORM. In that case, instead of creating an ORM class (`tableRow`), you create a dictionary with all keys (how depends on the data). Again you can use a context manager:

```
with engine.begin() as connection:
    connection.execute(tableRow.__table__.insert().
                       values([row_to_dict(row) for row in listOfRows]))
```

This would most likely be slightly faster but also less convenient. It works the same way as the session above only that it constructs the statement from the Core and not the ORM.

Comment: Thanks I have been reading up on sessions and going through the tutorials this morning but am just a little confused with the first choice, when you initialise session (by calling session = Session() ) don't you already have a session.begin() ? Wouldn't you be calling session.begin() twice with this method?

Comment: Ignore that last comment, I realise now that this was related to setting the autocommit in session to True to begin a transaction explicitly. And yes calling it from core is faster, but both work really neatly thank you!

Answer (score 17):

**UPDATE 2020-01-23**

the answer from @javex is outdated.

TLDR: You can use the session directly without calling `begin`. Just make sure `autocommit` is set to `false`

Long answer:

See the documentation for the Session
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html

> Warning
>
> The Session.begin() method is part of a larger pattern of use with the Session known as autocommit mode. This is essentially a legacy mode of use and is not necessary for new applications. The Session normally handles the work of “begin” transparently, which in turn relies upon the Python DBAPI to transparently “begin” transactions; there is no need to explicitly begin transactions when using modern Session programming patterns. In its default mode of autocommit=False, the Session does all of its work within the context of a transaction, so as soon as you call Session.commit(), the next transaction is implicitly started when the next database operation is invoked. See Autocommit Mode for further background.