# SQLAlchemy CSV import (into SQLite)?

Tags: python, sqlite, csv, sqlalchemy

I would like to load CSV file into SQLite coded using SQLAlchemy (to fit other code).

The command line load looks like this:

```
create table MYTABLE (...);
.separator ','
.import myfile.csv MYTABLE
```

(Avoiding per row `INSERT`s) Is there an equivalent SQLAlchemy operation?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19904176/transactions-and-sqlalchemy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.import` command is part of the [CLI](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#csv_import) and not part of the SQLite syntax.

If you want to import the content of the CSV file you can use the [python's csv reader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) and using [SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#insert-expressions) to insert every row (from the CSV) to the database:

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('myfile.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
...     tbl_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
...     for row in tbl_reader:
...         mytbl.insert().values(id=row[0], name=row[1], content=row[2])
```

Comment: How about start a transaction and commit every 100 (or 500) inserts?

Comment: I will see how transaction improves it. Thanks

Comment: that `rb` mode should be just 'r', otherwise you'll get ["_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8515053/1026).