# SQLAlchemy recursive insert into table

Tags: python, recursion, sqlalchemy

Is there a succinct way to perform an insert recursively, so that if the bulk insert fails, it tries, say, half of the records at a time. Currently, I am doing something like this:

```
def __recursive_import__(conn, insrt_func, validated_rows):
  try:
    result = conn.execute(insrt_func(validated_rows))
  except:
    __recursive_import__(conn, insrt_func, validated_rows[len(validated_rows//2):])
    __recursive_import__(conn, insrt_func, validated_rows[:len(validated_rows//2)])

def import_row(some_rows):
  return """INSERT INTO SomeTable {};""".format(some_rows)

with db.connect('some_db').begin() as conn:
  __recursive_import__(conn, import_row, rows_to_insert)
```

So if some rows error for *reasons...* (I am inserting into a db which houses a tremendous amount of business logic), it will keep trying smaller and smaller blocks. This is ugly, probably doesn't work, and ugly. Does sqlalchemy have a better way? Does anyone have a better way?

Comment: As a side note: do not use `__dunder_names__` unless you are providing a system-defined attribute like `__eq__`. Such names are reserved, and may be suddenly used in the future.

Comment: Why is your current solution not succinct?

Comment: I guess I am assuming that what I'm trying to do is pretty common, and therefore may perhaps already exist natively in sqlalchemy.

Comment: take a look at `transactions` and `SAVEPOINT` http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_transaction.html#using-savepoint 
a similar case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19904176/transactions-and-sqlalchemy