# Sqlalchemy gives Database locked error when Update is placed in for loop

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, sqlalchemy

There are 2 tables A and B. Both have columns named master and slave. Table A's master values must be updated to TableB's master ( For the rows with same slave values in Table A and Table B ).

As Sqlite doesn't have join method and doesn't support multi table updates I'm forced to consider other options.

The following code works.

```py
tableB = Table('table_B', metadata, autoload=True)
tableA = Table('table_A', metadata, autoload=True)


ku = tableA.update().where(tableA.c.master == "All for One" ).values(master = "Shigaraki Tomura")
ku.execute()
```

But when I try to use different values in .values() things get messy

```py
ls = select(columns=[tableA.c.master,tableB.c.master], whereclause=tableA.c.slave == tableB.c.slave).distinct()
rows = ls.execute()

for i,j in rows:
    ku = tableA.update().where(tableA.c.master == i).values(master = j)
    ku.execute()
```

Following are the error messages

```py
    File "/home/ehaacls/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 505, in do_commit
        dbapi_connection.commit()
    sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked

    raise exc.ResourceClosedError("This Connection is closed")
    sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This Connection is closed
```

Comment: Its been a while since I've done any work with databases but have you looked into using Transactions instead? [SQLAlchemy - Using Transactions](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#using-transactions). If I remember correctly, it should allow you to open a persistent connection to your database. You're probably trying to run too many individual queries on your database too fast. (but that's just a guess...)

Comment: Take a look at this related SO question as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19904176/transactions-and-sqlalchemy

Comment: @K-Log Thanks for the comment. Aren't queries I'm executing from the sqlalchemy core ( as mentioned from the link you posted ) ? If I start using Sessions, sqlite should take even longer.

Comment: take a look at this SO answer. It details why you may be getting the error and some possible fixes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26862809/operational-error-database-is-locked. You could also try something as simple as adding a sleep after each query in your for loop and see if that fixes it. If so then you’ve probably just hit the limitations of SQLite’s concurrency.